# Deserialize/Pulling a Spring's RestTemplate response from Atom source

Tags: spring

I'm trying to use Spring's RestTemplate to get a response from an atom source. Is there a way to easily pull values from the response or deserialize it?

The response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'                                               xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>
<id>https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/2.0/blah/verification/mx</id>
<updated>2013-03-19T19:47:02.805Z</updated>
<apps:property name='verified' value='false'/>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the feed with [Abdera](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ABDERA/Getting+Started) or [ROME](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/ROME/Home). They have nice representations of Atom feeds and feed entries with all their composing types.